# React state value is not equal to this.state.nameOfState

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a hard time trying to get the exact value of the state. For some reason, there seem to be a delay between the component's state and the call of the state.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: "",
        lastname: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

I have two `input`  that updates the state with `onChange`:

```
<input name="name" defaultValue={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
<input name="lastname" defaultValue={this.state.lastname} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
```

And finally, `handleChange`:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});

    console.log(this.state.lastname);
}
```

Everything seems to work except when I try to get a value of the state inside `handleChange`. For example, if a user types "ABCDE" for `name` and "12345" for `lastname`, if I check the component with the developer tool, the state says:

```
 name : "ABCDE",
 lastname: "12345"
```

But inside `handleChange`, `console.log(this.state.lastname)` says:

```
1234
```

It seems like every time, the last letter typed is missing even tho you can clearly see it inside `state`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind that is `this.setState` is **asynchronous**. As [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) documentation states:

> `setState()` enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state.
>
> React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

To reflect the changes I suggest to render the value of `lastName` as the following instead of checking with `console.log()`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      {this.state.lastname}
      <input name="name" defaultValue={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
      <input name="lastname" defaultValue={this.state.lastname} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Then on the UI you will see the current value of the state.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is, I'm using `console.log()` to check the `state` before eventually using these values for a `fetch` for example. Does that mean I will have to `fetch` inside `render()` ?

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a react.js related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067097/simple-html-element-in-react-js-code-does-not-work-in-xampp-localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

`setState` in react is async, so you don't see the most recent value.
If you want to console it, use callback as a second parameter to `setState`

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value}, () => console.log(this.state.lastname));


}
```