# Simple HTML element in react.js code does not work in Xampp localhost

Tags: php, reactjs

I am trying a very basic code in [react.js](https://reactjs.org/) :

File index.php has :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript file `my.js` has :

```
function formatName(user) {
  return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

const user = {
  firstName: 'Harper',
  lastName: 'Perez'
};

const element = (
  '<h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}!  </h1>'
);

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But as output I get raw JS code instead of JS being rendered:

```
<h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}! </h1>
```

How to make it run ?

**EDIT:**
You can  find the running code in codepen [here](https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/introducing-jsx). The `element` variable is declared as :

```
const element = <h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}!</h1>;
```

But I used single quotation around the element as otherwise I see error in the browser console:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**

**Edit2:** Fixed  the codepen link. New link is [this](https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/introducing-jsx).

Comment: There's no code at the codepen link.

Comment: see EDIT2 in OP

Comment: Second codepen appears to work. `const element = <h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}!</h1>;` also looks correct to me. What is the issue? Is react imported for the JSX usage, `import React from 'react';`?

Comment: No `import` is used. I gave the full code. Now I get the error in browser  console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`.

Comment: Are you trying to directly render JSX? As in, you use the react and reactDom scripts and use the globally defined React and ReactDOM? I think you need [react without-jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html).

Comment: I am a beginner and gave the full code in OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
const element = '<h1>Hello, ' + formatName(user) + '! </h1>';
```

Comment: same output. Does not solve the problem. I added `EDIT` in OP.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string to `render`. You need to pass JSX.

Try something like -

```
const element = <h1>{formatName(user)}</h1>
```

To make sure JSX is being understood, you need to include Babel preprocessor as well. Add the Babel CDN to your imports -

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js" integrity="sha512-kp7YHLxuJDJcOzStgd6vtpxr4ZU9kjn77e6dBsivSz+pUuAuMlE2UTdKB7jjsWT84qbS8kdCWHPETnP/ctrFsA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

#### A note for Node users

In a Node environment, where you cannot call ReactDOM.render(), you will need to make sure that you import `React`, like so -

```js
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: I am using PHP, not Node. Now I get this error in browser console : 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<''.

Comment: That perhaps means your JSX isn't being interpreted correctly. Please try adding the contents of `my.js` to the script tag itself.

Comment: It does not work even now. same error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to directly render JSX, but this requires a transpiler.

[react without jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

> Each JSX element is just syntactic sugar for calling
> `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`. So, anything you
> can do with JSX can also be done with just plain JavaScript.

Code could possibly look more like

```
function formatName(user) {
  return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

const user = {
  firstName: 'Harper',
  lastName: 'Perez'
};

const Element = ({ user }) => React.createElement(
  'h1',
  null,
  `Hello, ${formatName(user)}!`,
);

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Element, { user }, null),
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Or a bit more simply

```
function formatName(user) {
  return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

const user = {
  firstName: 'Harper',
  lastName: 'Perez'
};

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement('h1', null, `Hello, ${formatName(user)}!`),
  document.getElementById('root'),
);

// or

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Comment: which one is better - react with or without JSX ? How to directly render JSX ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed That is an opinionated questions. Obviously most prefer the JSX syntax for it's ease of use, but it requires a transpiling (similar to compiling) build step to translate the react JSX code to vanilla javascript that can be run in the browser. But you can skip the transpiling step if you start with vanilla JS. In your case it appears it is necessary to use vanilla JS.

Comment: Look at the very first example in this page https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html. 1) What is the whole tutorial of react.js written about - with or without JSX ? 2) Do I need a transpiler to run that code too ? 3) Where is it written about the transpiler in the tutorial link I gave ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed With JSX, it's the de facto standard way to write react apps. It's why "React without JSX" is located in the advanced guides.

Comment: Is ` React.createElement(` for react without JSX ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed `createElement` isn't expressly for rendering react without JSX if that is your question. The quote I shared says all of react JSX is syntactic sugar for this function.